# manage time-zones and local times of users

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

i'm building a mobile app.

I'm wondering how should i implement this kind of (simplified) scenario:

**Send users from all around the world a push notification at 08:00 AM every day of the year.**

The problem is that each user is in a different time zone. and some countries move their local time at summer\winter times by ±1 hour.

I can hold the UTC ± H for each user but still.. i will need to run the same task more than 24 times a day ([as the number of timezones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/current-number-time-zones.html))

Is there a better way?

Best practices to deal with scheduled tasks with multizone users?

Thanks.

Comment: You can define time zones using NSTimeZone....check the apple doc https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother segmenting and firing the push notifications for each time zone on the server because there is no way you can send them all out at exactly 8:00AM (your server would choke and die).  Just send all of the phones a silent push notification that tells the app when its supposed to set off the notification in local time.  Then in 
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any])

have each phone parse the silent notification, convert the request time into a local date time (see DateComponents) and create a UNNotificationRequest (iOS 10) or UILocalNotification (iOS 9 and earlier) that will fire off at 8AM on the correct date.

Comment: aaah, such a relief. I'm not familiar yet with the options i have to manage notifications on the client side. Great answer. Thanks!